# Is it possible to get the return code of a statement execute within an 'if' command?

Tags: ksh

I'm trying to execute a command and then display its return code if it failed:

```
if ! /bin/false
then
   tee >(mail -s "failed" $USER) <<EOF
     Failed with code $?
EOF
fi
```

The above always echo's '0' for me, but I'm expecting to see '1'.

The following works, but it is not as simple and also doesn't play well with `set -o errexit`.

```
/bin/false
ret=$?
if [ $ret -ne 0 ]
then
   tee >(mail -s "failed" $USER) <<EOF
     Failed with code $ret
EOF
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial test is flawed.

Try

```
if /bin/false ;then 
   echo status was $?
else
   echo "failed with status = $?"
fi
```

**output**

```
failed with status = 1
```

---

To isolate the use of true and false, try these on the cmd line

```
 /bin/true ; echo $?; /bin/false; echo $? ; ! /bin/false; echo $?
```

**output**

```
0
1
0
```

IHTH

Comment: Thanks. I simplified the original issue too far and made a typo in my example. The problem was the return code was being cleared when I used process substitution with `tee`. Storing it in a tempory fixed the problem.

Comment: OK, the subtle thing here is to NOT use the bang. The bang negates the return code, making it 0 when you try to use it. Using 'else' works.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this approach:

```
/bin/false || echo "Failed, return code = $?"
```